# How to prevent Ajax JSON call directly from browser in ASP.net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, attributes, asp.net-ajax, preventdefault

On my website I use an ajax called GetAllPatient(). It will return a JSON list. Now anybody can access it in browser. if anybody hits in a browser as [www.domain-name.com/controller-name.GetAllPatient()](http://www.domain-name.com/controller-name.GetAllPatient()) he looks my all patient.

How do I prevent directly access my data from the browser as JSON?

Comment: Do you mean to ask you want to prevent public access to your API endpoint?

Comment: Browser security prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the web page. This restriction is called the `same-origin policy`. The same-origin policy prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site.

Comment: @Jahangir Alam If anybody can access your server, please check have u enable [Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in your Startup.cs